# BigQuery does not recognise timezones when parsing

Tags: python, google-bigquery, timezone, dataflow, pytz

Taken from the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_zones):

> Time zones are used when **parsing** timestamps or formatting
> timestamps for display. The timestamp value itself does not store a
> specific time zone, nor does it change when you apply a time zone
> offset.
>
> Time zones are represented by strings in one of these two canonical
> formats:
>
> - Offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), or the letter Z for UTC
> - Time zone name from the tz database
>
> Example: 2014-09-27 12:30:00.45 America/Los_Angeles

This is what I am trying to do:

```
timestamp = dateutil.parser.isoparse(log['timestamp'])
log['local_timestamp'] = timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' Europe/Zurich'
```

Then, via a ApacheBeam Python Dataflow job, this entry is written into BigQuery and produces this error:

```
There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will not retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'local_timestamp', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Unrecognized timezone: Europe/Zurich'}]}, {'index': 1, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'local_timestamp', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Unrecognized timezone: Europe/Zurich'}]}]
```

I have tried different formats, for example appending `+2:00` at the end of the timestamp or different locations, even `America/Los_Angeles` as shown in the example. They all lead to unrecognized timezone errors. Only UTC seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong or the documentation is just not correct and only UTC timestamps are accepted?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide more details about your setup? From comment below answer you mention that you are using python dataflow job. Is it possible to provide how looks output after this job? Maybe it's missing some specific signs `"`, for example if you will use `Europe/Zurich` in bigquery you might get issue but if you will use `"Europe/Zurich"` it's ok. Could you also try to use: log['local_timestamp'] = timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' "Europe/Zurich"', adding `"` in timezone.

Comment: Hi Pjoter, thanks for your comment. What exactly would you like to see? The only lines that modify the timestamp are written above, then the entry is written into a bigquery table, that's it. If i try what you suggested, I get another error:
[{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'local_timestamp', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Could not parse \'2021-09-16 11:32:11 "Europe/Zurich"\' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]'}]}

Comment: Could you try to use `log['local_timestamp'] = timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + '.0 Europe/Zurich'` or `timestamp.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich'))`?

Comment: With the 1st option I get `'message': 'Unrecognized timezone: Europe/Zurich'` For the 2nd option I did `timestamp.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")` and got `'message': 'Unrecognized timezone: CEST'}`

Comment: The solution from @PjoterS sounds quite reasonable for me. Can you check whether it works without timestamp parsing (`strftime`): 
`str(timestamp.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')))` but straight with `str()` function producing the string value?

Comment: It seems `%Z` directive in `strftime()` parsing method doesn't bring the acceptable timezone format for the Bigquery conversion (full name timezones into UTC)  leveraging `tabledata.insertAll` REST API [method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) which is relevant for Dataflow streaming to Bigquery pipeline.

Comment: Hello, I tried again by using `str(timestamp.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')))`. The timestamp ends up in bigquery without errors with 2 hours added to it, as expected. However, the UTC ending remains and this is wrong, it should be CEST or Europe/Zurich instead. From  
2021-10-20 10:37:24 UTC, I get  
2021-10-20 12:37:24 UTC.

Comment: Does your concern about the Bigquery UI appearance of timestamp ending up with UTC but not CEST, or the conversion was made wrong way? If the conversion brings unexpected results share the source streaming timestamp as well as target inserted in Bigquery table.

Comment: I wrote it in the comment before. Source: '2021-10-20 10:37:24 UTC', Target: '2021-10-20 12:37:24 UTC'. The target should instead be '2021-10-20 12:37:24 CEST', so the conversion is wrong

Comment: Straight to your example, I've tried to check streaming insert with this [code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows?hl=en#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python) and I admitted the correctly inserted timestamps. Source streaming value: `2021-10-20 10:37:24+02:00`, target Bigquery value: `2021-10-20 08:37:24 UTC`. Would you be interested in sharing more details within the answer below?

Comment: Hey Nick, I think we are not understanding each other. Which details do you need?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, this conversion issue is not happening on my side, therefore I can share my code and test results in the answer, so you can check it on your side. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Yes that would be great. By reading the comment above, it seems like you are going from a CEST source to a UTC target. I am doing the reverse, trying to go from a UTC source to a CEST target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the basic [code sample](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python) from the documentation in order to check [tabledata.insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) method which is relevant for Dataflow streaming to Bigquery functionality, simulating the similar approach for timestamps transformation.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import dateutil, pytz
import dateutil.parser as dt

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of table to append to.
table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table"

t1=dateutil.parser.isoparse('2021-10-20 10:37:24')
t2=str(t1.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Zurich')))

rows_to_insert = [
    {u"t1": t2}
]

errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id, rows_to_insert)  # Make an API request.
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
    print (t2)
else:
    print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

It executed properly retaining timezone `Europe/Zurich`.

> New rows have been added. 2021-10-20 10:37:24+02:00

As long as Bigquery UI console saves timestamps in UTC format my test record was properly converted and inserted in the target table:

[image]

Hope this clarifies my efforts given in the comments.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the answer. It seems that the misunderstanding is in the conversion of the timestamp. I have a UTC timestamp and want to visualize the CEST correspondent time, not to convert the timezone to CEST.

Comment: As Bigquery holds the timestamps in UTC format I aimed to show that my timestamp is correctly inserted into Bigquery table considering that the CEST time zone threshold has been correctly reflected in UTC time view. If you want to visualize raw UTC  records to the custom zone then consider to look at specific Bigquery [datetime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions?hl=en#datetime) functions. Is it reasonable for you?

Answer (score 0):

No, BQ accepts other than UTC timezones too.

```
SELECT
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS datetime_ymdhms,
  DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    "Europe/Zurich") AS datetime_tstz;
```

[image]

What I guess the problem is ' Europe/Zurich'. Can you try 'Europe/Zurich'?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My problem happens when parsing the timestamp while inserting into bigquery via a python dataflow job, not when running a query. I have tried 'Europe/Zurich' without the space, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Batch inserts into BigQuery, you may want to check the files that are generated in the temporary Cloud Storage path before being loaded in.
With that information you can check if it is a Dataflow issue (most probably, the format generated by your code is not good) or a BigQuery issue (for any strange reason the TZ is not being accepted).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. My pipeline is a streaming pipeline :)